# If condition for array with numbers and string

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have an array that contains numbers and string. I would like to create result array that contains only specific data with help of cycle and If condition, but I have problems with data type definition. I can't define array as int, because I have str data too.

```
result = []
Data = ['5','10','NA','15']
for i in range(0, len(Data)):
    if Data[i] > 10 or Data[i] =="NA":
        result.append(Data[i])
```

I receiving errors like this:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'NA'

Comment: try changing your if statement to include a type conversion to int: `int(Data[i])`

Comment: Why can't you mix ints and strings in the list…?

Comment: You're making your life unnecessarily hard there with `range` and `i`… You can simply loop over the values directly: `for val in Data: if val ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the string is numeric and then use its int form for the comparison.

```
result = []
Data = ['5','10','NA','15']
for i in range(0, len(Data)):
    if (Data[i].isdigit() and int(Data[i]) > 10) or Data[i] =="NA":
        result.append(Data[i])
print(result) # outputs ['NA', '15']
```

Comment: You could also simply check for "NA" first and probably safely assume (?) that everything that's not "NA" should be a number…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the method **isnumeric()** --
[https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isnumeric.asp#:~:text=The%20isnumeric()%20method%20returns,considered%20to%20be%20numeric%20values](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isnumeric.asp#:%7E:text=The%20isnumeric()%20method%20returns,considered%20to%20be%20numeric%20values).

You can use it before checking if its > 10:

```
    `if Array[i].isnumeric() and Array[i] > 10:
         result.append(Data[i])
     elif: Array[i] = 'NA'
         result.append(Data[i])
```

`

Comment: There is a slight difference between isnumeric and isdigit. Technically isdigit is the right method to use here since isnumeric with also return True for inputs like '一二三四五'.isnumeric().